# How to know the real size of a web page?

Tags: performance

I wan't to know the real size of a web page (HTML + CSS + Javascript + Images + etc.) but from the browser side, maybe with a software, Firefox Add-On or similar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use firefox, and get FireBug.

Then get the YSlow addon for firefox.

For IE, you can get the DebugBar which comes pretty close to giving the same information.

Answer (score 5):

[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) is a [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin (Firebug is a FireFox plugin), and it works great.

If you meant the entire website, you could get [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) (Software) and download the entire site... just be careful.. people don't like it when you do that!

Answer (score 0):

I think the Firefox Plugin [Extended Statusbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1433) can do that for you.

It will give detailed information about what has been downloaded, including the size of the downloaded data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to use firefox and its plugins, you can use [Pingdom Tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox now embedded developper tools (in the `tools` menu, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) has a ["Network" tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) which allows for detailed monitoring of size and load time of a webpage.  The context menu (right click) allows to save data in [HTTP archive format (HAR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har).